# Google Chrome doesn't run from task scheluder

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to configure a task on **Task Scheduler** on **Windows 7**. It's a very simple one - running Google Chrome with an argument, which suppose to open a website with Chrome.

The command is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" google.com
```

It works totally fine from `cmd` and from a `batch file`.

But thus far, I could not set it to run on **Task Scheduler**.
There are a few methods I tried, and all of them end up with the same result.

**Option 1:**

- Action: `Start a program`
- Program/script: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`
- Add arguments (optional): `google.com`
- Start in (optional): blank

**Option 2:**

- Action: `Start a program`
- Program/script: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`
- Add arguments (optional): `google.com`
- Start in (optional): `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\"`

**Option 3:**

- Action: `Start a program`
- Program/script: `D:\Scripts\openWebSite.bat`
- Add arguments (optional): blank
- Start in (optional): blank

**Option 4:**

- Action: `Start a program`
- Program/script: `D:\Scripts\openWebSite.bat`
- Add arguments (optional): blank
- Start in (optional): `D:\Scripts\`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**On Actions Tab:**

- action:

  ```
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
  ```
- Arguments:

  ```
  http://www.Google.com
  ```

**On General tab:**

- Make sure you have the correct permissions to run this in task
  scheduler:

  `run with highest permissions`.
- And select

  `run only when user is logged on`.

[image: created task]

Comment: This checkbox is already checked, and I tried with this action but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Try putting just chrome.exe as the action and please make sure you're putting http://www.google.com as the argument

Comment: Okay I've just done it on mine, action is start a program, full path to chrome.exe in quotes "C:\program files\google\application\chrome.exe" and argument is https:// www. google.com Double check that path though to the exe because that was from memory in my extremely tired state! Haha

Comment: Just realised my original comment didn't show the https like I intended just a hyperlink! *facepalm*

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Could you confirm exactly what you are doing, eg create task, actions... Thanks

Comment: Did you get to work it on your computer? If so, please share the steps.

Comment: Yeah just 2 seconds ago and I recreated it for sanity, worked fine both time.  Open task scheduler, create basic task, add trigger, action, start a program, browse to chrome, argument the full path of the website including https:// and www. And then finish and run it.

Comment: OK, I got it to work, the problem was checking the "Run whether the user is logged on or not". You can edit your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Ah right I never knew you were trying to get it to run while logged off

Comment: @DewiJones, is there a way to close the browser after the task completes? I have a task that needs to run pretty frequently and it leaves a bunch of open windows.

Comment: @swagata I would just kill the process using taskkill /Im chrome.exe

Comment: Thanks @DewiJones. That's what I ended up doing in a separate scheduled task. I was wondering if there's a way to do it automatically once the page completes executing.